# Playing video in my iPhone application (MPMoviePlayer)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the code below to attempt to play a video in my iPhone app. However, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer =  [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: i want play movie(or) video in iPhone(storyboard) application

Answer (score 1):

Where is your play statement ??

`[moviePlayer play];`

Comment: NSInvalidArgumentException                                        [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter
it show like a error

Comment: NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
    //    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer =  [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease];
    
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [moviePlayer play];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

Comment: make sure ur movie is there in compiled resources in build phases

Comment: now i change  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath]; now i got black screen with no error,but i did,t got answer